# Maaser-Specialized Accountants

Tags: product-recommendation, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes

Are there accountants who specialize in calculating the exact amount of maaser one should give and adjust 'deductions from maaserable income' as per different shittot?

Comment: A new app just came out that tallies this kinda stuff. Perhaps it will be of help. https://ez-maaser.com/

Comment: Thank you, Nahum! Not at all what I came here looking for, and incredibly useful just the same!